# What is the error with my code to connect a SQL Server database with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

See my code shown below - where is the error or what is the mistake I made? Console doesn't show anything, just a black blank..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace sql_connect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Database=Db_test;Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30");

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Well Done");
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You failed!" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: did you try to debug it ? and one more thing try adding catch (Exception e),yeah i agree you have added SqlException,give a try by catching other than sql exception.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have created Db_test on the SQLExpress?
Check DB connection with UDL file first. More info [here](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/65525.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting any error might be a problem with connection. You would get  possibly a timeout soon. Please check if you can reach this dB from some other tool (SQL Server Management Studio for instance). Might be a typo in the connection string.

Side note: put sqlconnection in using to make it always disposed after you stop using it.